# Playwrigth: Can't set cookies in the context

Tags: typescript, cookies, playwright

I'm trying to set some cookies using a `globalSetup` in `Playwright`

However If I go to the network tab when debugging using the `npx playwright test --headed` option to run tests, the cookies are not present.

The globalSetup is invoked and the cookies in the `storage-state.json` file —as `storageState`— are saved.

My project runs in `localhost:3000` and I've tried several combination of `domain` in the injected cookie such as `localhost`, `.localhost`, `127.0.0.1:3000`, `localhost:3000`, with no luck.

my **global.ts**

```
export default async function globalSetup() {
  const now = new Date();

  await prisma.user.upsert({
    // some prisma upsert here
  });

  const storageStatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'storage-state.json');

  // Check if the storage state file exists, and if it does, load the cookies
  try {
    const storageState = path.resolve(__dirname, 'storage-state.json');
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState });

    await context.addCookies([testCookie]);
    await context.storageState({ path: storageState });

    // log context cookies
    const cook = await context.cookies();
    console.log(cook);
    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error loading storage state:`);
  }

  // Save the cookie to the storage state file
  const newStorageState = { cookies: [testCookie], origins: [] };
  try {
    await fs.writeFile(storageStatePath, JSON.stringify(newStorageState), 'utf8');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error saving storage state:`);
  }
}
```

my **playwright.config.ts**

```
  export default defineConfig({
    // Look for test files in the "tests" directory, relative to this configuration file.
    testDir: 'src/__tests__/e2e/',
  
    // add global setup (auth mainly)
    globalSetup: 'src/__tests__/e2e/setup/global.ts',
  
    // Run all tests in parallel.
    fullyParallel: true,

    use: {
      // Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`.
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    // Configure projects for major browsers.
    projects: [
      {
        name: 'chromium',
        use: {
          ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
          storageState: 'src/__tests__/e2e/setup/storage-state.json',
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

and my super simple test

```
test.describe('', () => {
  test('context available', async ({ page }) => {
    // tried this too
    // const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir);
    // const page = await context.newPage();
    // await context.addCookies([testCookie]);
    await page.pause();

    await page.goto('/');

    const productCardImage = page.locator('[datatest-id="product-card-image"]').first();
    await productCardImage.click();

    // rest of the test
  });
});
```

I even tried generatin a test using `codegen` that navigates to google and a combination of domains `google.com`, `.google`, `.google.com`, `google` and with no luck, so I suspect it has to to with my `globalSetup` method.

this is the `storage-state.json` file being populated once the setup is executed.

```
{"cookies":[{"name":"next-auth.session-token","value":"d52f0c50-b8e3-4326-b48c-4d4a66fdeb64","url":"http://localhost:3000","expires":1678926378,"httpOnly":true,"secure":false,"sameSite":"Lax"}],"origins":[]}
```

And this is [the project](https://github.com/esponges/fer-personal-site/tree/main/src/tests/e2e) in case somebody want's to see the full code.

Comment: Is the JSON file written properly?

Comment: Hey thanks, I've updated my question with the json file, and the file it's correct. Wouldn't the setup fail if the file was unexistant or wrongly formed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some issues in the database, using a fresh & seeded database and setting the `expires` to `-1` solved the issue as per commented [here](https://github.com/juliusmarminge/t3-complete/issues/37).